# Gas estimation failed error

Tags: solidity, metamask, gas, etherscan, gas-estimate

Following error is coming:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032", "message": "execution reverted" } }
```

My code is:

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    pragma solidity ^0.8.8;
    
    import "./PriceConverter.sol";
    
    contract FundMe {
    
        using PriceConverter for uint256;
    
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50;
        mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
        address[] public funders;
    
        address public owner;
    
        constructor(){
            owner = msg.sender;
        }
    
        function fund() public payable{
            require(msg.value.getConversionRate() >= minimumUSD, "amount not satisfied");
            funders.push(msg.sender);
            addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        }
    
        function withdraw() public onlyOwner{
            
            for(uint256 funderIndex = 0; funderIndex <= funders.length; funderIndex ++){
                address funder = funders[funderIndex];
                addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
            }
            // resetting the array
            funders = new address[](0);
            
            (bool sendSuccess, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
            require(sendSuccess,"send failed");
    
        }
    
        modifier onlyOwner{
            require(msg.sender == owner, "Sender is not owner");
            _;
        }
    }
```

Following is PriceConverter.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

library PriceConverter{
 
function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface pricefeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 price,,,) = pricefeed.latestRoundData();

        return uint256(price * 1e10);

    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethamount) public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUSD = (ethPrice * ethamount) / (1e18);

        return ethAmountInUSD;
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

}
```

Comment: This error is not due to your solidity code. But rather the amount of gas you are giving to function to execute. Every operation on the blockchain has its cost in gas. And you are just being warned that you don't use enough to run it for such a "distance"

Comment: how to fix this problem? as the transaction is failing even on forceful execution

Comment: This is usually fixed on the caller side. What program/framework are you using to call these functions?

Comment: Please, can you provide more information about error? And can you share 'PriceConverter.sol' smart contract code?

Comment: Hi Kerry99, the PriceConverter.sol code is updated for you to check